# How to import a file with data and pass it to a list in python?

Tags: python, file

I have a file with data `.dat` where inside it, they have 3 columns with values ​​referring to certain quantities, given the form:

[apr.dat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZR64U.png)
| Mass density  | Pressure | Energy density |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
|2.700000e-02   |1.549166e-11|2.700000e-02  |
|2.807784e-02   |1.650004e-11|2.807784e-02  |
|2.919872e-02   |1.757406e-11|2.919872e-02  |
|3.036433e-02   |1.871798e-11|3.036433e-02  |
|3.157648e-02   |1.993637e-11|3.157648e-02  |
|3.283702e-02   |2.123406e-11|3.283702e-02  |
|3.414788e-02   |2.261622e-11|3.414788e-02  |
...

I just want to use the second and third column of data (without using the title). I was able to open the file using

```
data = open(r"C:\Users\Ramos\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\\apr.dat")

print(data.read())
```

And then, I tried to turn it into a list with the following code:

```
import numpy as np

data = open(r"C:\Users\Ramos\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\\apr.dat")

data2 = np.shape(data)
print(data2[1])
```

But when I tried to insert the numbers of column 2 and column 3 in a list, it gave an error. Is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you please post the full stacktrace of the error?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\IRamos\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\EOS.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(data2[0])
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need at this point to use numpy.

```
with open(r"C:\Users\Ramos\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\apr.dat", 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    next(reader)  # skip 1st line
    array = [[float(row[1]), float(row[2])] for row in reader] # skip column 0 (1st col)
```

**EDIT:** if you want separate lists for x and y:

```
x, y = list(zip(*array))
```

Comment: I tried this form, but it gives an error for me: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: can you provide you data file content (no screenshot please)?

Comment: I suspect the last line is empty or partially filled

Comment: and in your first post, the last backslash in file path should not be doubled (you type a raw string).